# org-mode How to fold an arbitrary block of text

Tags: org-mode

How to fold arbitrary blocks of text?

Something like #BEGIN_SRC org .. but don't edit in another mode... using <language> 'org' doesn't really work, for example, enter on a `[[link]]` fails.  Drawers don't seem to work except after a heading. BEGIN _EXAMPLE, or _VERSE _QUOTE all have issues.  I want something like a heading with an end marker (that isn't another header).

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org
whatever text... edit etc the same as all other org text
but allow folding this block 
(and enter on '[[link]]' should still work)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: There are several hits on Google search for folding an org-mode source code block (including ones that I have previously answered) -- have you looked at any of those previous threads to see if those answer your question?  My recollection is that org-mode *may* also have something built-in to support this.

Comment: Just in case it's useful for others: At least in recent versions of emacs (I'm runing 28.2) org-mode will fold arbitrary blocks. e.g `#+BEGIN_myblock ... #+END_myblock` and stuff inside the block is treated as normal org text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quote` block will do some of what you want. You can get a quote block through the templating system -- type `<q`, then hit `<TAB>`, to make a quote block. Quote blocks are foldable and respect org's markup syntax, so links still work. They *do* get incredibly strange if you try to insert a header inside one, so maybe give that a miss.

Comment: #+BEGIN_QUOTE ...  #+END_QUOTE ... <qTAB  is a quick way to create one (I learned 2 new things there).  Now I see #+BEGIN_CENTER and #+BEGIN_JUSTIFYLEFT and #+BEGIN_JUSTIFYRIGHT work too (though QUOTE seems best).  This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [vimish-fold](https://github.com/mrkkrp/vimish-fold) package to achieve arbitrary code folding in any mode in Emacs.